# Angular 7 - ngOnInit is not getting called

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-lifecycle-hooks

We do have a main angular app that references library representing sub-area of a main app.

We wanted to have ability of defining separated routes in our library.

Eg:

- app has root paths: /app
- library has child paths: /library

After going to route /app/library, it should redirect to the component stored in the library.

We have achieved that by using lazy loading. It only works when you connect routes using 'loadChildren' property of a Route in a main app.

We were also forced to apply workaround suggested by Angular team [Lazy loading module from library package located in node_modules fails to build](http://loading%20module%20from%20library%20package%20located%20in%20node_modules%20fails%20to%20build) - which is usage of proxy/wrapper module in order to lazy load a library within an angular workspace or node modules.

Anyway, we got it all working.

**And now the problem starts:**

Angular lifecycle events (like: ngOnInit) don't work in components in our library. When we referenced library using eager loading (and at the same time lost wanted by us routing), angular hooks started working just fine.
What could be wrong in here?

Is it Angular's issue? We wanted our app to be well structured and that's why we separated some areas into separated libraries. However, we're close to giving up and moving all the code into just main app.

Edit:

Routing in app.module (forRoot, lazy loading):

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'app', loadChildren: './lazy/lazy-wrapper.module#LazyWrapperModule' },
];
```

Routing in (LazyWrapperModule, which is inside main app) (forChild):

```
{ path: '', component: LibraryComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Routing in Library (forChild):

```
{ path: 'library', component: TargetComponent },
```

Comment: In both the eager loading and lazy loading library component does show up on the screen but lifecyle hooks don't work in case of eager loading, right? Or in case of lazy loading library component doesn't appear at all on the screen? Also will you add the code for routing configurations if possible?

Comment: @emkay yes, in both cases library component shows up:
(eager = hooks working, routing not) (lazy = hooks not working, routing working); I have edited question to show routing we're using

Comment: So there is one app-module and lazy-wrapper-module  with corresponding routing modules, right? Is there a different module for target-component or it's inside the lazy-wrapper-module?

Comment: @emkay there is a main app (with AppModule and LazyWrapperModule inside) and the external Library (with LibraryModule, LibraryComponent, TargetComponent) in it

Comment: can you recreate the issue on stackblitz

Comment: @Patryk I am little confused about your directory strucutre. I created a small stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-35mpzw. Can you verify if this is how your code structure and routing looks like?